# Handling button tag in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

In Red bus app i am trying to click on search buses button,I tried in many ways like this

```
driver. find element(by. xpath("//button"(contains(text()='Search Buses')")).click();
```

still getting unable to locate the element anyone having solution for this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your attempted `xpath` syntax is incorrect. You should try as below :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Search Buses')]")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Search Buses']")).click();
```

You can find it using `By.id()` as well which would be much faster than `xpath` as :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("search_btn")).click();
```

Follow these links to learn more about `xpath`

1. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp
2. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp
3. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp